# Timeout problem installing Kubeflow in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubeflow

After following the documentation to install Kubeflow in Google Cloud Platform, in the step of the kubeflow installation, Kubectl wait for inaccessible resources and waiting long timeouts.

In the command
`make apply`

```
kubectl --context=gke-manager wait --for=condition=Ready --timeout=500s -f ./build
# If this takes long, you can view status by:
cd common/managed-storage && make status
# For resources with READY=False, debug by:
kubectl --context=gke-manager -n env-kubeflow describe <KIND>/<NAME>

kubectl --context=gke-manager wait --for=condition=Ready --timeout=100s -f ./build \
        || kubectl --context=gke-manager get -f ./build


timed out waiting for the condition on sqlinstances/kubeflow-kfp
timed out waiting for the condition on storagebuckets/env-kubeflow-kfp
NAME                                                 AGE     READY   STATUS         STATUS AGE
sqlinstance.sql.cnrm.cloud.google.com/kubeflow-kfp   3m24s   False   UpdateFailed   3m23s

NAME                                                           AGE     READY   STATUS         STATUS AGE
storagebucket.storage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/env-kubeflow-kfp   3m24s   False   UpdateFailed   3m24s
kubectl --context=gke-manager wait --for=condition=Ready --timeout=500s -f ./build
```

Probably it seems a IAM and Google Project problem of some dead resources still present in kubernetes, but inaccessible, but the fact is that I deleted all the kubernetes clusters inside that GCP Project.

Documentation: https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/distributions/gke/deploy/deploy-cli/

## Update 1

It seems a GCP Region problem

```
~/gcp-blueprints/kubeflow/common/managed-storage/build: $ kubectl --context=gke-manager describe -f ../build
Name:         kubeflow-kfp
Namespace:    env-kubeflow
Labels:       app=managed-storage
              kf-name=kubeflow
Annotations:  cnrm.cloud.google.com/management-conflict-prevention-policy: none
              cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id: env-kubeflow
API Version:  sql.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
Kind:         SQLInstance
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-02-15T09:51:07Z
  Finalizers:
    cnrm.cloud.google.com/finalizer
    cnrm.cloud.google.com/deletion-defender
  Generation:  1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  sql.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
        f:labels:
          .:
          f:app:
          f:kf-name:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:databaseVersion:
        f:region:
        f:settings:
          .:
          f:availabilityType:
          f:locationPreference:
            .:
            f:zone:
          f:tier:
    Manager:      kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-02-15T09:51:07Z
    API Version:  sql.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:finalizers:
          .:
          v:"cnrm.cloud.google.com/deletion-defender":
          v:"cnrm.cloud.google.com/finalizer":
      f:status:
        .:
        f:conditions:
        f:observedGeneration:
    Manager:         cnrm-controller-manager
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2022-02-15T09:51:08Z
  Resource Version:  9447
  UID:               c2070b0a-5266-4ba7-8c09-a30fc46ae7c6
Spec:
  Database Version:  MYSQL_5_7
  Region:            europe-central2
  Settings:
    Availability Type:  ZONAL
    Location Preference:
      Zone:  us-central1-c
    Tier:    db-custom-1-3840
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-02-15T09:51:08Z
    Message:               Update call failed: error applying desired state: summary: Error, failed to create instance kubeflow-kfp: googleapi: Error 400: Request contains unrecognized GCE zone when creating or updating an instance., errorUnrecognizedGceZone, detail:
    Reason:                UpdateFailed
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
  Observed Generation:     1
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age                   From                    Message
  ----     ------        ----                  ----                    -------
  Warning  UpdateFailed  17m (x12 over 17m)    sqlinstance-controller  Update call failed: error applying desired state: summary: Error, failed to create instance kubeflow-kfp: googleapi: Error 400: Request contains unrecognized GCE zone when creating or updating an instance., errorUnrecognizedGceZone, detail:
  Normal   Updating      6m37s (x18 over 17m)  sqlinstance-controller  Update in progress


Name:         env-kubeflow-kfp
Namespace:    env-kubeflow
Labels:       app=managed-storage
              kf-name=kubeflow
Annotations:  cnrm.cloud.google.com/force-destroy: true
              cnrm.cloud.google.com/management-conflict-prevention-policy: none
              cnrm.cloud.google.com/project-id: env-kubeflow
API Version:  storage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
Kind:         StorageBucket
Metadata:
  Creation Timestamp:  2022-02-15T09:51:07Z
  Generation:          1
  Managed Fields:
    API Version:  storage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        .:
        f:conditions:
        f:observedGeneration:
    Manager:      cnrm-controller-manager
    Operation:    Update
    Time:         2022-02-15T09:51:07Z
    API Version:  storage.cnrm.cloud.google.com/v1beta1
    Fields Type:  FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .:
          f:cnrm.cloud.google.com/force-destroy:
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
        f:labels:
          .:
          f:app:
          f:kf-name:
      f:spec:
        .:
        f:location:
    Manager:         kubectl-client-side-apply
    Operation:       Update
    Time:            2022-02-15T09:51:07Z
  Resource Version:  4662
  UID:               69661a78-e2bf-436c-9e69-fe170b4d056b
Spec:
  Location:  europe-central2
Status:
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:  2022-02-15T09:51:07Z
    Message:               Update call failed: cannot make changes to immutable field(s): [location]
    Reason:                UpdateFailed
    Status:                False
    Type:                  Ready
  Observed Generation:     1
Events:
  Type     Reason        Age                  From                      Message
  ----     ------        ----                 ----                      -------
  Warning  UpdateFailed  7m2s (x18 over 18m)  storagebucket-controller  Update call failed: cannot make changes to immutable field(s): [location]
viumeai@cloudshell: (env-kubeflow)
```

Comment: Looks like there is a conflict between region and zone. In the configuration file, You are using Europe as region but zone you are using is US.  Do changes and confirm.